# Echo/return is adding whitespace before variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code, which grabs information from a database, then creates a path to an image and returns it, which I use as the img src on another page.

Here's the function:

```
function getMainImage ()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]' AND main = 'y' LIMIT 1";
    include 'connect.php';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $path = "images/t_$row[username]_$row[number].$row[ext]";
    return $path;
}
<img src="<?php echo getMainImage(); ?>" width="40" height="40" />
```

The output when looking at the page source is:

```
<img src=" images/t_image_3.jpg" width="40" height="40" />
```

There is an extra space being added from the function before "images/". I've tried trimming the path, and even trimming the function when calling it, but neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: beware of SQL injection!

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: why open/close the db handle each time you call this function? that's rather wasteful if the function's called multiple times.

Comment: How else would you code the function? @MarcB

Comment: mysql handles should be opened once and then left open for the life of the script. put your `connect.php` at the top of the script. while mysql's connection protocol is fairly lightweight/fast, if thos function is called repeatedly in a single script, you're going to waste a lot of cpu time on something that isn't at all necessary.

Comment: This code might also be vulnerable to [XSS](http://phpmaster.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/).  Recommend at minimum using `<?php echo htmlentities(getMainImage(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>` (modify to match your character encoding if necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the help, in the process of converting my functions to use PDO now. Assuming I have a page, which calls multiple functions that use the database, would it be better practice to open the database connection at the top of the page, and close it at the bottom? Or open/close in each function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## include

The whitespace you're seeing almost certainly comes from this line:

```
include 'connect.php';
```

Check what you have in the file `connect.php`, and delete any whitespace before the opening `<?php`, and if it has a `?>`, simply delete it.

Answer (score 1):

My friend @AD7six is right! (and what he recommends is the best thing to do!).

But, if you've having a hard time "catching" the space and you want to work around it you can do instead:

```
$img = getMainImage();
echo "<img src='\"images/t_" .  $img . "\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this small solution:

```
    require_once 'connect.php';

        function getMainImage (){
            $User = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[username]);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE username = '$User' AND main = 'y' LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $connetion) or die (mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($row) $path = "images/t_$row[username]_$row[number].$row[ext]";
            return isset($path) ? $path : 'default_url_to_img';
        }

<img src="<?= getMainImage(); ?>" alt="some txt" width="40" height="40" />
```