# Why AJAX success prefers empty spaces in result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an AJAX request towards PHP, but when debugging the function success is returning **empty spaces** before the result. I can not identify the inconvenience.
I have already made requests before and I had not had this problem.

```
$('.eliminarve').click(function() {
  var token = $(this).attr('id');
  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append('eliminarVEntrevista', true);
  datos.append('tokenVE', token);
  $.ajax({
    url: "../../views/ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#loading").removeClass('d-none');
    },
    success: function(result, status, xhr) {
      $("#loading").addClass('d-none');
      console.log(result);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(xhr);
      //alert(retorno); 
    }
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['eliminarVEntrevista']) and isset($_POST['tokenVE'])) {
  echo "hello";
}
```

Answer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echo/return is adding whitespace before variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901946/echo-return-is-adding-whitespace-before-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the editor you're using is adding `/n` or another new line hidden character to your output. Open the file in something like Notepad++ to check if there are any hidden (or special) characters in the file.